# Exporting whole map from ArcMap to GeoTIFF not just current view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion

I like to export my whole map which is composed of both raster and vector data to geotiff (or other raster format) in ArcMap 10.1. If I select file->export, only the current view is exported. I want to export the whole map in for instance the 1:100 000 scale.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This shows up in our [FAQ for GeoTIFF](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotif?sort=frequent).

Answer (score -1):

Change to layout view.
Zoom to the desired scale.
Export the map.

Comment: It is not possible to add georeference in layout mode.